# How to view a list of databases under server in SQL Anywhere like we do in MSSQL

Tags: database, sqlanywhere

I am very new to SQL Anywhere. I have been working MSSQL for a long time.

So in MSSQL, if we need to see the list of database under server, we can see that under Server Explorer.

How can I do same in SQL Anywhere?

I have just installed SQL Anywhere 16 and have no idea how to find Server name etc.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a program called "SQL Central" (scjview.exe) that was installed with SQLAnywhere server. Run that and you should be able to see the servers.